# Terminate and retrieve solution in ILOG after a certain time limit in python

Tags: python, cplex, ilog

I am using ILOG CPLEX from Python and I am running an Integer optimisation problem that takes sometimes more than 12 days to complete . I need to terminate the program after a certain time limit regardless of solution is obtained or not. Can anyone let me know how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code:

```
p = cplex.Cplex()

p.parameters.timelimit.set(time_limit_in_seconds)
```